# Can Selenium WebDriver read a captcha when I'm trying login?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, captcha

I should have a question about testing with Selenium WebDriver. I test logging into an application where, in addition to user name and password, I also need to authorize using a security image (some numbers). I think Selenia's testing is not possible, but I'm sure if anyone has any experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can’t do it by itself. You have at least three options:

1. Ask developers to create special value that will always accept.
2. Specify list of IP addresses, so requests from this IPs will always accept any captcha value.
3. Disable captcha for special test user account.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will ask our programators for except of IP. Can you tell me more about - Use image recognition libraries. This is free for disposition?

Comment: Actually, the services that I saw were not free, and does not have 100% of successful recognitions, so it is not a good option, because it can lead to flacky tests. You choosed the right way, hope your developer can help you with it.

Comment: So, have you figure out this issue with IP's list?

Comment: yes, It was easy add my IP to list... now is function all. Thanks